# Wrapping delimited lines, retaining first column, with minimum final length

Tags: ruby, perl, awk, command-line

Looking to split up lines of content, retaining a headword.

I do a ton of text processing, and I like to use unix one-liners because they are easy for me to organize over time (vs. tons of scripts), I can easily chain them together, and I like (re)learning how to use classic unix functions. Often I will use a short awk, perl, or ruby one-liner, depending on which is the most elegant.

Here I have lines with X number of comma-delimited items. I want to divide these up, retaining the headword.

INPUT:

```
animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare, goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck, camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider, deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit, elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth, shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
```

OUTPUT:

```
animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare
animals = goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck
animals = camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider
animals = deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit
animals = elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth
animals = shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
```

Algorithm details:

- input lines consist of a headword, then equals-sign, then a comma delimited list of at least 1 item.
- In this example, most words are singles, but words could contain spaces (e.g. "horseshoe crab" at the end)
- Split is at 9 items, UNLESS there are <3, in which case the final split could yield 12 on a line
- There are multiple lines. e.g. the next line could be planets.

I had an idea to escape spaces, then use unix fold, and then awk to pull down the first column. This works exactly like the above:

```
echo "animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare, goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck, camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider, deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit, elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth, shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab" \
| \tr ' ,' '_ ' \
| fold -s \
| perl -pe 's/=/\t/; s/^_/\t_/g;' \
| awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1==""{$1=p} {p=$1} 1' \
| tr '\t _'  '=, '
```

But it only considers character length (not item count), and fails to consider my special case that I don't want <3 items hanging on the final line.

I think this is an elegant little puzzle, got ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=" = "} {
   s = $2
   while (match(s, /([^,]+, ){1,9}(([^,]+, ){2}[^,]+$)?/)) {
      v = substr(s, RSTART, RLENGTH)
      sub(/, $/, "", v)
      print $1, v
      s = substr(s, RLENGTH+1)
   }
}' file

animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare
animals = goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck
animals = camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider
animals = deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit
animals = elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth
animals = shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
```

Pay special attention to regex used here `/([^,]+, ){1,9}(([^,]+, ){2}[^,]+$)?/`

That matches 1 to 9 words separated with `,`  delimiter. This regex also has an optional part that matches upto 3 words before end of line.

Comment: Interesting. I am digesting that regex. That's a nice idea to match an optional group by the EOL.

Answer (score 3):

With Perl, one way

```
perl -wnE'
    ($head, @items) = split /\s*[,=]\s*/; 
    while (@items) { 
        @elems = splice @items, 0, 9;
        if (@elems < 3) { $lines[-1] .= ", " . join ", ", @elems }
        else            { push @lines, join ", ", @elems }
    }
    say "$head = $_" for @lines; @lines = ()
' file
```

or

```
perl -wnE'
    ($head, @items) = split /\s*[,=]\s*/; 
    push @lines, join ", ", splice @items, 0, 9  while @items; 
    $lines[-2] .= ", " . pop @lines  if 2 > $lines[-1] =~ tr/,//;
    say "$head = $_" for @lines; @lines = ()
' file
```

Shown over multiple lines for readability, and can be copy-pasted into a bash terminal as such, but they can also be entered on one line. Tested with an added line of 11 (9+2) items.

Notes

- [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split)-ing by either `,` or `=` extracts the head-word first, and then the items on a line
- [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice) removes and returns (the first `9`) elements, which joined by `,`  generate a line to print, until all elements are processed.  The last group is added to the previous line-to-print instead if it has fewer than 3 elements
- In the second version all elements are processed and then the last line-to-print checked for whether it need be added to the previous one instead, by counting commas in it

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` program. Written and tested in GNU `awk` should work in any `awk`.

Where I have created an `awk` variable named `numberOfFields` which contains number of fields you want to print(as segregated with new line as per shown samples).

```
awk  -v numberOfFields="9" '
BEGIN{
  FS=", ";OFS=", "
}
{
  line=$0
  sub(/ = .*/,"",line)
  sub(/^[^ ]* =[^ ]* /,"")
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    printf("%s",(i%numberOfFields==0?OFS $i ORS line" = ":\
    (i==1?line " = " $i:(i%numberOfFields>1?OFS $i:$i))))
  }
}
END{
  print ""
}
'  Input_file
```

***OR*** Above code is having `printf` statement in 2 lines(for readability purposes) if you want to have that into a single line itself then try following:

```
awk  -v numberOfFields="9" '
BEGIN{
  FS=", ";OFS=", "
}
{
  line=$0
  sub(/ = .*/,"",line)
  sub(/^[^ ]* =[^ ]* /,"")
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    printf("%s",(i%numberOfFields==0?OFS $i ORS line" = ":(i==1?line " = " $i:(i%numberOfFields>1?OFS $i:$i))))
  }
}
END{
  print ""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk  -v numberOfFields="9" '            ##Starting awk program from here, creating variable named numberOfFields and setting its value to 9 here.
BEGIN{                                  ##Starting BEGIN section of awk here.
  FS=", ";OFS=", "                      ##Setting FS and OFS to comma space here.
}
{
  line=$0                               ##Setting value of $0 to line here.
  sub(/ = .*/,"",line)                  ##Substituting space = space everything till last of value in line with NULL.
  sub(/^[^ ]* =[^ ]* /,"")              ##Substituting from starting till first occurrence of space followed by = followed by again first occurrence of space with NULL in current line.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                   ##Running for loop here for all fields.
    printf("%s",(i%numberOfFields==0?OFS $i ORS line" = ":\  ##Using printf and its conditions are explained below of code.
    (i==1?line " = " $i:(i%numberOfFields>1?OFS $i:$i))))
  }
}
END{                                    ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print ""                              ##Printing newline here.
}
'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***Explanation of `printf` condition above:***

```
(
  i%numberOfFields==0                   ##checking if modules value of i%numberOfFields is 0 here, if this is TRUE:
    ?OFS $i ORS line" = "               ##Then printing OFS $i ORS line" = "(comma space field value new line line variable and space = space)
    :(i==1                              ##If very first condition is FALSE then checking again if i==1
       ?line " = " $i                   ##Then print line variable followed by space = space followed by $i
       :(i%numberOfFields>1?OFS $i:$i)  ##Else if if modules value of i%numberOfFields is greater than 1 then print OFS $i else print $i.
     )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F'[=,]' -v min=3 -v max=9 '
{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      if ( (i-1) % max == 1 && (NF-i+1 > min) ) {
         if ( i > max ) print newline
         newline=$1 "="
         pfx=""
      }
      newline=newline pfx $i
      pfx=","
  }
  print newline
}
' raw.dat
```

Sample data:

```
$ cat raw.dat
animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare, goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck, camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider, deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit, elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth, shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
planets = mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto, vulcan, arrakis, hoth, naboo
numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
numbers2 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
```

With `-v min=3 -v max=9` we get:

```
animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare
animals = goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck
animals = camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider
animals = deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit
animals = elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth
animals = shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
planets = mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto
planets = vulcan, arrakis, hoth, naboo
numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
numbers2 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
numbers2 = 10, 11, 12, 13
```

---

Addressing OP's comment about using one-liners ...

While this `awk` script can certainly be jammed into a one-liner I'm guessing OP will a) find it hard to edit/maintain and b) too easy to screw up if having to (re)type over and over again.

One (obvious?) idea is to wrap the `awk` code in a function, eg:

```
splitme() {
    awk -F'[=,]' -v min=$1 -v max=$2 '
    { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
          if ( (i-1) % max == 1 && (NF-i+1 > min) ) {
             if ( i > max ) print newline
             newline=$1 "="
             pfx=""
          }
          newline=newline pfx $i
          pfx=","
      }
      print newline
    }' "${3:--}"
}
```

**NOTES:**

- parameterized the `min` and `max` values so as to pull from the command line
- parameterized the file reference to pull from either the command line (`$3`) or stdin (`-`)
- OP can add more logic to verify/validate input parameters as needed

Whether calling as a standalone against a file:

```
$ splitme 3 9 raw.dat
```

Or calling in a pipeline:

```
$ cat raw.dat | splitme 3 9
```

Both generate:

```
animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare
animals = goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck
animals = camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider
animals = deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit
animals = elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth
animals = shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
planets = mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto
planets = vulcan, arrakis, hoth, naboo
numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
numbers2 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
numbers2 = 10, 11, 12, 13
```

Comment: This is pretty, and I like the clear field separators and parameters at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two Ruby solutions to process one line. The variable `str` holds one line (the line beginning `'animals = ...'` in the example).

**#1 Use a regular expression**

```
RGX = \A\w+| *= *|(?:[^,]+, *){0,10}[^,]+\z|(?:[^,]+, *){9}
```

```
def break_line(str)
  headword, _, *lines = str.scan(RGX)
  lines.each { |line| puts "#{headword} = #{line.sub(/, *\z/, '')}" }
end
```

```
brake_line(str)
animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare
animals = goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck
animals = camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider
animals = deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit
animals = elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth
animals = shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
```

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
RGX =
/
\A         # match beginning of string
\w+        # match one or more word chars (e.g., "animals")
|          # or
[ ]*=[ ]*  # "=" preceded and followed by zero or more spaces
|          # or         
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  [^,]+    # match one or more chars other than a comma
  ,[ ]*    # match a comma and zero or more spaces
){0,10}    # end non-capture group and execute 0-10 times
[^,]+      # match one or more chars other than a comma
\z         # match end of string
|          # or
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
 [^,]+     # match one or more chars other than a comma
 ,[ ]*     # match a comma and zero or more spaces
){9}     # end non-capture group and execute 1-7 times
/x         # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7kKGfT/1)

When executed for the example `str` we would find the following.

```
headword
  #=> "animals"
_
  #=> "="
lines
  #=> ["lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, ",
       "mule, hare, goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, ",
       "frog, bug, fish, duck, camel, squirrel, owl, ",
       "chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider, deer, ",
       "tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, ",
       "rabbit, elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, ",
       "crab, leopard, moth, shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab"]
```

Ruby has a convention of using the variable `_` in situations when its value is not subsequently used in calculations. This is mainly to so-inform the reader.

**#2 Extract and group words**

```
def break_line(str)
  headword, *words = str.split(/ *[,=] */)
  groups = words.each_slice(9).to_a
  if groups[-1].size < 3
    groups[-2] += groups[-1]
    groups.pop
  end
  groups.each { |group| puts "#{headword} = #{group.join(', ')}" }
end
```

```
brake_line(str)
animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare
animals = goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck
animals = camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider
animals = deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit
animals = elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth
animals = shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
```

By way of a partial explanation, we would obtain the following for the example:

```
headword
  #=> "animals"
words
  #=> ["lizard", "bird",,..."horseshoe crab"]
groups
  #=> [["lizard", "bird", "bee", "snake", "whale", "eagle",
        "beetle", "mule", "hare"],
       ["goose", "horse", "mouse", "pig", "dog", "frog",
        "bug", "fish", "duck"],
       ["camel", "squirrel", "owl", "chicken", "pigeon", "lion",
        "sheep", "bear", "spider"],
       ["deer", "tiger", "lobster", "dinosaur", "cat", "goat",
        "rat", "cricket", "rabbit"],
       ["elephant", "crow", "fox", "donkey", "monkey", "butterfly",
        "crab", "leopard", "moth"],
       ["shark", "salmon", "shrimp", "mosquito", "horseshoe crab"]]
```

As the element of `groups` contains more than two elements (it contains five), `groups` is not subsequently modified. Had the last line been permitted to have at most 14 (rather than 11) elements it would have been changed to

```
["elephant", "crow", "fox", "donkey", "monkey", "butterfly", "crab",
 "leopard", "moth", "shark", "salmon", "shrimp", "mosquito", "horseshoe crab"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F"[=,]" -v max="9" '{
        for(i=2; i<=NF; i+=max){
                row = ""
                for(j=i; j<=i+max-1; j++){
                        row=row $(j) ","
                }
                gsub(/,+$/, "", row)
                printf "%s=%s \n", $1, row
        }
    }' input_file

animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare
animals = goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck
animals = camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider
animals = deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit
animals = elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth
animals = shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
planets = mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto
planets = vulcan, arrakis, hoth, naboo
numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
numbers = 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
cars = mercedes benz, bmw, audi, vw, porsche, seat, skoda, opel, renault
cars = mazda, toyota, honda
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a while to modify my solution to make it work across both `gawk` and `mawk` by performing the equivalent of `$1 = $1` towards the end of the regex chain;

`$(NF!=NF=NF)` expands to `NF != (NF=NF)` internally, which is always false, so the whole thing just means `$0`, but embedding `$1=$1` within it  :

---

```
 input ::

     1  animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare, goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck, camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider, deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit, elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth, shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
     2  planets = mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto-cuz-it-shoudlve-been, planetX

 command ::

 [mg]awk '
 BEGIN {
     FS = (OFS = " = ") "*" 
   _=__ = (___="[^,]+")"[,]"
           gsub(".",_,__)
     __ = (__)_ "(("_")?("_")?"___"$)?"
 
      _ = ORS } gsub(__,"&"_ $1 OFS)+gsub("[,]"_,_)+sub((_)"+([^,]*)$","", $(NF!=NF=NF))' 

 output (mawk 1.3.4) ::

     1  animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare
     2  animals = goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck
     3  animals = camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider
     4  animals = deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit
     5  animals = elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth
     6  animals = shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
     7  planets = mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto-cuz-it-shoudlve-been, planetX

 output (gawk 5.1.1) ::

     1  animals = lizard, bird, bee, snake, whale, eagle, beetle, mule, hare
     2  animals = goose, horse, mouse, pig, dog, frog, bug, fish, duck
     3  animals = camel, squirrel, owl, chicken, pigeon, lion, sheep, bear, spider
     4  animals = deer, tiger, lobster, dinosaur, cat, goat, rat, cricket, rabbit
     5  animals = elephant, crow, fox, donkey, monkey, butterfly, crab, leopard, moth
     6  animals = shark, salmon, shrimp, mosquito, horseshoe crab
     7  planets = mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto-cuz-it-shoudlve-been, planetX
```